# I want to find rows where all my tags can be applied

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, tags

I have a table as follows

[image]

I want to find a u_t_upload_id where both u_t_tag_id -  1 and 2 is applied.That is in this case it is 1 since u_t_tag_id - 1 and 2 is applied to u_t_upload_id 1.

[image]

Is there any simple query to solve this problem

**What I given above is an example what is really want is to display u_t_upload_id where all given u_t_tag_id is applied.That is 1 and 2 is an example of input.**

Comment: I have updated my code to a tested and effective piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT u_t_upload_id
FROM uploads_tags
WHERE u_t_tag_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY u_t_upload_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u_t_tag_id) = 2
```

The `HAVING` clause checks for `u_t_upload_id` groups having 2 *distinct* `u_t_tag_id` values. Since, the `WHERE` clause filters out records other than the ones having `u_t_tag_id IN (1, 2)`, the query is guaranteed to return those `u_t_upload_id` being related to *both* `u_t_tag_id` values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple query to solve this problem

```
SELECT u_t_upload_id FROM uploads_tags WHERE (u_t_tag_id=1 OR u_t_tag_id=2) GROUP BY u_t_upload_id HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Comment: This query will also return a `u_t_upload_id` value related to *just one* `u_t_tag_id` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT Distinct(u_t_upload_id) FROM table WHERE u_t_upload_id = 1 AND u_t_upload_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning relational Division, so I'm not 100% confident about the following code.  But here goes...

```
SELECT *
FROM tblTable AS X
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM tblTable AS Y
                   WHERE Y.u_t_tag_id IN ( 1, 2 )
                     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                      FROM tblTable AS Z
                                      WHERE Z.u_t_upload_id = X.u_t_upload_id
                                        AND Z.u_t_tag_id = Y.u_t_tag_id )
                 )
ORDER BY u_t_upload_id;
```

I tested the above code against the test database created using the following script...

```
CREATE DATABASE RelationalDivision002;
USE RelationalDivision002;
CREATE TABLE tblTable
(
    u_t_id          INT,
    u_t_upload_id   INT,
    u_t_tag_id      INT
);
INSERT INTO tblTable( u_t_id,
                      u_t_upload_id,
                      u_t_tag_id )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 1 ),
       ( 2, 1, 2 ),
       ( 3, 2, 3 ),
       ( 4, 3, 4 ),
       ( 5, 3, 5 ),
       ( 6, 3, 6 ),
       ( 7, 2, 1 ),
       ( 7, 3, 1 );
```

I tested the code using any combination of the inner-most `SELECT`'s WHERE conditions.  The above is the only to produce the desired output.

I have nearly figured out why.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to contact me.

Thank you.